# Sending binary data over http in the url

Tags: http, binary-data

I am trying for a way to pass binary data to a server over http, via the URL field in the browser. Is there a way to bypass the automatic http encoding done by the browser so I can just encode the data by myself.

e.g.: Instead of the byte with value 48, to fill in the URL %30 so that the browser doesn't re-encode the url and I end up with %2530

Solved: To whom may encounter similar problems in the future. You can do so by using wget parameter

*--restrict-file-name=ascii*

Which basically ensures that ***'%'*** won't be escaped

Comment: Why do you need to do the encoding yourself?

Comment: Because on the server side there is a binary that expects this sort of data, and I was wondering whether there was a way to do this without writing a http client from scratch.

Comment: If you just put a `0` in, that's equivalent to putting `%30`. There shouldn't be any issues doing so.

Comment: As e.g. suggests, that was a mere example. There are ways to do so for the first 127 ASCII characters (the readable ones) but the problem is with the ones in range (127-255]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do so, by writing my own tcp client to connect to the http server and transmit the request, by inputting it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use [base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) encoding, that's what it's designed to do.

Comment: He can't modify the server side, so no option. Skyel, you should put that in the question.

Comment: This may cause issues becaue the base64 encoded string can contain '/'. I think base32 encoding is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [base62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745025/convert-a-string-into-base62) encoding.

The encoded string doesn't contain any character that will be URL-encoded.